# Use XML output as input of a template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to create key value pairs of all the elements of an XML.
Example:

```
<a>
   <b>1</b>
   <c>2</c>
</a>
```

Will return:

```
<KEY_VALUE_PAIR>
   <KEY>a/b</KEY>
   <VALUE>1</VALUE>
</KEY_VALUE_PAIR>
<KEY_VALUE_PAIR>
   <KEY>a/c</KEY>
   <VALUE>2</VALUE>
</KEY_VALUE_PAIR>
```

But, my problem is that I would like to take the input xml as string.

So, instead of having this as input :

```
<a>
   <b>1</b>
   <c>2</c>
</a>
```

I would like to use this :

```
<XML>
   <content>&lt;a&gt;&lt;b&gt;xyz&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt;</content>
</XML>
```

This is my code :
It almost works, the creation of the key value pairs is ok, but instead of taking the XML in XML/content, it will create key value pairs of the input xml.

```
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/XML/content">
  <xsl:value-of select="/XML/content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="CreateNotificationValues"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="CreateNotificationClear"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/" name="CreateNotificationValues">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[count(child::*) = 0]">
     <KEY_VALUE_PAIR>
      <KEY>
       <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>/</xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </KEY>
      <VALUE>
       <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </VALUE>
     </KEY_VALUE_PAIR>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/KEY_VALUE_PAIR" name="CreateNotificationClear">
 </xsl:template>
```

How can I use this :

```
<xsl:value-of select="/XML/content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

as input xml of another template ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use this :
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="/XML/content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
> ```
>
> as input xml of another template ?

**You can't** -- An XSLT transformation can be performed on a well-formed XML document, but the result of the above XSLT instruction is just a text node (its final representation may *look like* XML, but this is a 1-dimensional string -- not a tree of nodes.

In order to use a string as a tree (parsed XML document) you need, well ... to *parse* this string and the tool that does this is called an *xml parser*.

**Neither an XSLT 1.0 or an XSLT 2.0 transformation can take a string and parse it into an XML document tree**.

In XSLT 3.0 there might be a standard function **[`parse-xml()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml)** which does exactly that.

**In XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 it is necessary to invoke an extension function**, written in your favourite PL, that will parse the string into an XmlDocument object and return this object back to the transformation.